# R: filtering a data.table with dplyr fails

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am on Windows using R 4.0.2 and data.table 1.13.0 and dplyr 1.0.0

This is such a weird bug that I can't make reproducible example.

```r
library(data.table)
df2 = structure(list(total_amount = 9.39999961853027, tip_amount = 0, 
               total_amount = 9.39999961853027, passenger_count = 1L), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

# this works
df2[total_amount > 10, ] 

# this works
df2 %>% 
  data.frame %>%
  filter(total_amount > 10)

# this doesn't work!!!
df2 %>% 
  filter(total_amount > 10)
```

and gives error `Error in .subset2(chunks, self$get_current_group()) :  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex`

This is so perplexing. What is going?

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example.   `mtcars %>% data.frame %>% filter(carb == 4)` works for me

Comment: What is the difference between the second and the third filtering?

Comment: Could it be an upgrade issue? Sometimes odd bugs happen when installing the package from source, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63118464/r-filterting-a-data-table-with-dplyr-fails

Comment: @akrun that is why it is hard to reproduce. Only fails on a particular data.

Comment: can you use `dput` of that and check if it can be reproduced i.e. `dput(head(df2), 20)`

Comment: I am using 4.0.2

Comment: This seems to be on the `dplyr` side, I'm not sure why the difference vs. `data.frame`

Comment: Fwiw, I see the useful error `"Error: Column \`total_amount\` must have a unique name"` with r 3.3.3 dplyr 0.7.4 rlang 0.4.0 so it might be a regression/bug in tidyverse since that point (since you're on a more recent dplyr)

Answer (score 2):

The issues seems to be that if two columns have the SAME name then it errors.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your data.table is badly designed. You have two columns called total_amount. How in this case is dplyr supposed to know what to do when filtering? It looks at your filter condition, and then looks for total_amount in the table. It finds two columns with that name and then rightly throws an error as there is no way of knowing which column to use. dplyr is doing what it should be doing. Essentially your data is not tidy, and that is what dplyr expects.

Comment: However, all of `data.table`, `dplyr`, and base `data.frame` by themselves can return an answer without error. So at least the inconsistency is cause for consternation.

Comment: I am not sure if this is cause for much consternation. The tidyverse is designed around a philosophy that says you should not create a dataframe like the OP's. Yes, you can do it within data.table and data.frame. But you cannot do it within tibble, which correctly forbids duplicated column names.